# gitflow: bugfixing an upcoming release

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I started to use the [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) concept recently and I have a question about the release-* branches.

Whenever I make a new release(-branch), I perform some kind of a validation to verify that the essential parts of the software still function as expected. Every now and then, this reveals some bugs that need fixing before this code can be accepted as the new stable-release version.

If those bugs have a simple solution, I can make a single commit on that release-* branch, merge it to develop, and I'm done.
However, I'm not quite sure what I should do when the bug is a bit more complicated.

- I can't use a feature-branch:
  Those start from develop, which has moved on since the release was
  initiated.
- I don't think I should use a hotfix branch:
  I need to start from a release-branch instead of master, and I don't want the changes to be merged into master either (at least not before the complete release was properly validated).
- I don't think I should work directly on the release-branch:
  This can generate broken code on the release-branch (code that is still under development is almost never good code)

Maybe I should use a releasefix-* branch or something similar...? Any ideas?

Comment: Its basically what you want to do. if you follow the gitflow so you should do use release branch, if your bug fix is huge as you say it still should be derived from release and merged back to release

Comment: You can also cancel the release, fix the bug in develop and create a new release.

Comment: I could do that if no new features would have been added since the release was created. However, new features have been added already and they shouldn't be in this release, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a small discussing with my colleagues, I used a new branch-type: releasefix

Branches of this type should be

- Branched of the current release-branch (assuming new releases may only be initiated when no other releases are still pending)
- Merged into the release-branch (its parent) and the develop-branch
- starting with the `releasefix-` prefix

I used a new branch-type for it to make sure no release-fixes would accidentally be merged in the wrong branches.

Comment: For the people downvoting this answer: please comment why you think this is a bad answer, then maybe I could learn from it

Comment: I upvoted this. The advice sounds reasonable. Unfortunately on SO there are some misguided souls who believe self-answered Q&A should be held to a higher standard.

Answer (score 2):

For people finding this in 2018. There is now a `git flow bugfix` command that can be used like this:

```
git flow bugfix start [branchName]
```

For this particular question `[branchName]` would be the release branch.

Comment: I believe this only works if you have installed the git flow collection found here: https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh